# Game Maker JS Extension

Tags: javascript, game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

Hi I'm looking to add javascript functions to game maker, but the format of them is like this:

```
companyname.initialize({ 
    soundMuteCallback: muteSound,           // optional
    soundUnmuteCallback: unmuteSound        // optional
});
```

And in the file they look like this

```
this.initialize = function(params) {
    companyname.getSharedEventCenter().postEvent(SharedEventKeys.API_INITIALIZE);

    _isInitialized = true;

    if (typeof params !== "undefined") {
        var muteSoundCallback = ("soundMuteCallback" in params && typeof params["soundMuteCallback"] === "function") ? params["soundMuteCallback"] : undefined;
        var unmuteSoundCallback = ("soundUnmuteCallback" in params && typeof params["soundUnmuteCallback"] === "function") ? params["soundUnmuteCallback"] : undefined;
        _adsManager.setSoundCallbacks(function() {
            typeof muteSoundCallback === "function" && muteSoundCallback();
            [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("audio"), function(element){
                element.muted = true;
            });
        }, function() {
            typeof unmuteSoundCallback === "function" && unmuteSoundCallback();
            [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("audio"), function(element){
                element.muted = false;
            });
        });
    }

    _tryShowAd();
};
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this in game maker? I don't know what information to put in the extension function properties.

Thanks,
Mitchell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new function that Game Maker can understand and then use that to create your object and the constructor you are showing here.

```
company.initialize = function(params) {
    companyname.getSharedEventCenter().postEvent(SharedEventKeys.API_INITIALIZE);

    _isInitialized = true;

    if (typeof params !== "undefined") {
        var muteSoundCallback = ("soundMuteCallback" in params && typeof params["soundMuteCallback"] === "function") ? params["soundMuteCallback"] : undefined;
        var unmuteSoundCallback = ("soundUnmuteCallback" in params && typeof params["soundUnmuteCallback"] === "function") ? params["soundUnmuteCallback"] : undefined;
        _adsManager.setSoundCallbacks(function() {
            typeof muteSoundCallback === "function" && muteSoundCallback();
            [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("audio"), function(element){
                element.muted = true;
            });
        }, function() {
            typeof unmuteSoundCallback === "function" && unmuteSoundCallback();
            [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("audio"), function(element){
                element.muted = false;
            });
        });
    }

    _tryShowAd();
};

function createMuteCallback() {
    muteCallback = function () {
        // Code to handle the callback
    }
    return muteCallback;
}

function createUnmuteCallback() {
    unmuteCallback = function () {
        // Code to handle the callback
    }
    return unmuteCallback;
}

function createCompany (mute, unmute) {
    if (mute == 1) {
        soundMuteCallback.createMuteCallback();
    }

    if (unmute == 1) {
        soundUnmuteCallback.createUnmuteCallback();
    }

    company.initialize(soundMuteCallback, soundUnmuteCallback);
}
```

So all of that goes in the same .js file. Create a new extension in Game Maker. Add the .js file to that extension. Add a function named createCompany with two optional parameters.

Then when you call createCompany(1, 1); in your Game Maker code, the .js file will run and will initialize the company object with the two callback functions.

Hope this helps.